# Nepali visiting Europe from Thailand

Tags: schengen, nepali-citizens

I hold a Nepali passport and I'd like to visit some of the Schengen countries in Europe.  What is the procedure?

Comment: @pnuts That would depend very much on where in Europe the asker wants to go.

Comment: @pnuts Fair point -- I never think to check the tags. Really, the question itself should include that kind of information.

Comment: @pnuts The asker put it in the tags, so we can assume it's true. I put it in the question so that people would see it. Unless the average reader of this site is much more diligent about checking tags than I am, I think it does need to be in the question text.

Comment: @pnuts Tags are meta-data to assist searching and filtering. Information that's necessary to answer the question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 6):

For those who contemplate the adventures of international travel to Europe there is always a starting point where the first steps are taken.

For people who need visas to travel to Europe (that includes YOU in this particular case), the first step is to define your agenda. It means an itinerary of where in Europe you want to go, where you expect to say, and how you plan to maintain yourself during your visit.

Everything that follows is predicated on this first step so it is critical to make your agenda as detailed as possible. This will require lots of planning and preliminary research on your part. In the case of the *"'box standard' Europe 101"*, you would nail down the important European capitals and your accommodation plans for each one.

I emphasise this point because the current era has it that open-ended travel to Europe for Nepalese nationals is not an option. Lots of people make this assumption and there's where problems start. Your agenda needs to be written down and make sense. It needs to demonstrate that you have spent lots of time preparing it and that you understand the implications of intercity travel and making advanced reservations. If your agenda is kept in your head, or if it doesn't make sense, you can expect problems.

If your itinerary is **coherent** and you have uncontested access to the funds needed *AND your personal circumstances indicate that you are not a "risky applicant"*, then getting a visa becomes a purely mechanical exercise.

Once your agenda is fully nailed down you can return to us and ask what to do next, we'll want to know aspects of your agenda like where is your first arrival into Europe and where you will be spending the most time.

And a final bit: we emphatically recommend that you avoid making a misconceived or premature visa application. Doing so can result in a major disruption to your plans and leave you with an ugly transcript on their computers that includes your photo and biometrics.